# footer green border on android browser

Tags: android, html, css

When I open my site http://www.gestaoeventos.com on Defy (Android 2.1 update 1 Browser version 7) there is a strange green border on my footer and a retangular yellow box on bottom left side.
Do you know what this means?

Comment: The above home page link you provided redirects to a Login Page for Desktop PC's. Is this issue happening at the Login Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML head you have defined Mobile.css for media query `screen and (max-device-width: 480px)`. What means: apply Mobile.css styling on device with screen width smaller than 480px.

You can fix your issues on removing `border` and `background-color` properties from Mobile.css:

```
#rodape {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
#rodape2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Good luck, Ronaldo!

Comment: Thank you. I could not remember this anymore and It's difficult and my cell phone don't have tools to debug.

Comment: You can use Android SDK on Windows to to build, test, and debug http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.